# Issue on converting time from local to UTC at DST end date while using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo) method

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I have an application that converts local time to UTC and stores it in the database. I encountered this problem while I was testing the conversion during a particular date - 1st November, 2015(the date on which the Daylight savings time ends(the clock goes back to 1.00AM on reaching 2.00AM)).

My local system timezone is (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
I converted the time 2015-10-31 01:49:00.000 to UTC, the output was 2015-10-31 08:49:00.000.

but

when I tried to convert 2015-11-01 01:49:00.000 to UTC, the output was 2015-10-31 09:49:00.000.

Isn't this wrong? why did the converted time increase by an hour on 1st November?

This is my method,

```
DateTime universalFormatDateTime = localDateTime.Value.GetUniversalFormatDateTime();
utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(universalFormatDateTime, _timeZoneInfo);
```

Comment: What does "universal format date time" mean in the first place? That *sounds* like it's actually in UTC, but apparently not... you may want to rename your variable and method to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't this wrong? why did the converted time increase by an hour on 1st November?

Because that's when the clocks change, as you say.

The problem is that "2015-11-01 01:49:00.000" is ambiguous in Pacific Time - it occurs twice, once at 2015-11-01T08:49:00Z and once at 2015-11-01T09:49:00Z.

A `DateTime` [*can* remember which of those you mean](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime), but it depends on how you came up with the value. If you've just parsed this from text somewhere, you basically don't have enough information - it doesn't specify a single instant in time.

If you were to use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library instead, then when converting from `LocalDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime` you'd be able to specify how you wanted ambiguity to be handled - so that *may* be an option for you... but it depends on where the value came from, and whether you know that it was *always* the second occurrence or *always* the first.

If you still want to use `TimeZoneInfo`, you can use [`TimeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.isambiguoustime) and [`TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime) to detect local times which occur twice or zero times due to time zone shifts, and then handle those appropriately in your app.

Comment: the time is parsed from a datepicker control

Comment: @user1890098: So how would you know whether the user meant the *first* occurrence of 01:49 or the second?

Comment: @user1890098 - Consider testing user input with the `IsAmbiguousTime` and `IsInvalidTime` methods of the `TimeZoneInfo` class.  Invalid times should fail validation, while ambiguous time might be either distinguished via application logic, or by prompting the user to select which one they meant.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Have added a reference to those in the answer - thanks.